# .env Nuxt JS doesn't resolve routes in generate option correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use Nuxt JS's 2.9.2 generate object to generate dynamic pages as static files using my `.env` file to pull a URL, I'm having difficuility in getting it to properly link up:

**nuxt.config.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
import pkg from './package'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  mode: 'universal',

  env: {
    blog_api: process.env.BLOG_API || "http://localhost:3000/articles/blogs.json"
  },

  /*
  ** Build directory
  */
  generate: {
    dir: 'dist-next',
    routes: function () {
      return axios.get(`${process.env.blog_api}`)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data.blogs.map((blog) => {
          return '/posts/view/' + blog.title
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

The above code, more specifically `${process.env.blog_api}`, can't seem to resolve the routes, despite it working perfectly if I replace it with my own local domain.

**.env**

```
BLOG_API="http://my-local-domain.clone/articles/blogs.json"
```

EDIT:

Updated code with my config, http://my-local-domain.clone/articles/blogs.json is inside of `static/articles`

Answer (score 0):

You should use dotenv module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

More Info about configuration with NUXT you have here:

https://samuelcoe.com/blog/nuxt-dotenv/

You probably want to set your env property in nuxt.config.js, for example:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    BLOG_API: process.env.BLOG_API_URL,
  },
```

In your component, you can now use them :

```
      makeAsyncCall({
        to: process.env.BLOG_API,
      })
```

Comment: I'm already including Dotenv, with the following error upon generating the routes: `Error: Request failed with status code 400`

Comment: Can you create gist or sandbox to see better ?

Comment: My codebase is pretty large, so would take some time to flesh out the minimal code to get this working. I've updated my description above with my exact config, include `.env` file

Comment: Did you put env file at the root of your project ?  Did you add  env variable to nuxt.config.js like in tutorial ?

Comment: I do not need BLOG_API inside of a component, I'm referencing it further down? In the generate property in the nuxt config file